# can not read special charachter while reading data from URL in android

Tags: android, webview

I am reading the contents from a URL and modifying the string and again loading the data in the Webview. But its unable to load the properly.Attaching the scrrenshot. Any Guess

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(benefitsCore.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            webView.loadData(base64, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
        } else {
            String header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>";
            webView.loadData(header + benefitsCore, "text/html; chartset=UTF-8", null);
        }
```

[image]

```
private String rzBenefitsCoreText() {
    String rzCoreText = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.bby_rz_sliver_benefits_url));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));//"ISO-8859-1")
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        builder.append(inputLine);
        rzCoreText = builder.toString().replace("Silver member", "Core member");
        Log.i("Data:", rzCoreText);
        br.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rzCoreText;
}
```

Comment: You might try changing "chartset=UTF-8" to "charset=UTF-8" for starters.

Comment: @DavidWasser no not like that.

Comment: Maybe you are decoding the contents incorrectly when you are reading them in the first place. Show that code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It is based on the fonts on your phone. I mean if you look up the string in the debugger nothing is wrong however in my case font was not covering all unicode characters related to my text so some characters was not displayed correctly,as yours.
May be using other fonts help you to resolve this case.